# Set of points equidistant to two n - 1 dimensional affine subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Say we're in $\mathbb{R^n}$ with the standard inner-product and its induced norm.  Let $A, B \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ be two affine subspaces of dimension n - 1.  Let $C = \{x \in \mathbb{R^n} : \mathrm{dist}(x, A) = \mathrm{dist}(x, B) \}.$
Intuitively, I want to say that $C$ is a finite union of affine subspaces just from visualizing what happens in $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $\mathbb{R^3}$.  However, I couldn't find a nice proof on my own or anything on here.  Does anyone have any results or ideas about this?

Comment: It won't be just finite unions of affine subspaces; if you start with a plane and a normal line in $\Bbb{R}^3$, the resulting locus is the boundary of a double cone.

Comment: Or, indeed, in $\Bbb{R}^2$, if you have a line and point not on the line, you've now got the locus definition of a parabola.

Comment: Ah right.  My mistake is I was only thinking of n - 1 dimensional affine subspaces.  I wonder if anything interesting happens if A and C have dimension n - 1.

Comment: In that case, you'll either get one hyperplane (when $A \neq B$ are parallel), the entire space (when $A = B$) or the union of two hyperplanes. Do you want me to write up an answer to this effect?

Comment: What's the general technique?  I can try on my own.  I'll also edit the question to be about n - 1 dimensional spaces.

Comment: Well, I would start with a nice orthonormal basis. When $A, B$ are not parallel, they intersect in an affine space of codimension $2$. Form an orthonormal basis for $A \cap B$, and extend it to $\Bbb{R}^n$ by adding in two orthonormal unit vectors $u, w$. Argue that the distance to $A$ and $B$ depends only on the coefficients of $u$ and $w$, hence reducing the problem down to the $n = 2$ case. Then use simple Euclidean geometry.

Comment: Ok that sounds very nice.  Thank you.

Comment: If you get somewhere, don't forget to post it as an answer!